# i run a parcel and i get some issue

Tags: node.js, parceljs

postcss  <=8.4.30
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service in postcss - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hwj9-h5mp-3pm3
Regular Expression Denial of Service in postcss - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-566m-qj78-rww5
PostCSS line return parsing error - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7fh5-64p2-3v2j
No fix available
node_modules/css-modules-loader-core/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-extract-imports/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-local-by-default/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-scope/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-values/node_modules/postcss
node_modules/purgecss/node_modules/postcss
css-declaration-sorter  <=5.1.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/css-declaration-sorter
css-modules-loader-core  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-modules-extract-imports
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-modules-local-by-default
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-modules-scope
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-modules-values
node_modules/css-modules-loader-core
cssnano  <=4.1.11
Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-preset-default
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/cssnano
cssnano-preset-default  <=4.0.8
Depends on vulnerable versions of css-declaration-sorter
Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-util-raw-cache
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-calc
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-colormin
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-convert-values
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-discard-comments
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-discard-duplicates
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-discard-empty
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-discard-overridden
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-merge-longhand
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-merge-rules
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-minify-font-values
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-minify-gradients
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-minify-params
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-minify-selectors
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-charset
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-display-values
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-positions
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-repeat-style
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-string
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-timing-functions
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-unicode
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-url
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-whitespace
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-ordered-values
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-reduce-initial
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-reduce-transforms
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-svgo
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-unique-selectors
node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
cssnano-util-raw-cache  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/cssnano-util-raw-cache
postcss-calc  4.1.0 - 7.0.5
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-calc
postcss-colormin  <=4.0.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-colormin
postcss-convert-values  <=4.0.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-convert-values
postcss-discard-comments  <=4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-discard-comments
postcss-discard-duplicates  1.1.0 - 4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-discard-duplicates
postcss-discard-empty  1.1.0 - 4.0.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-discard-empty
postcss-discard-overridden  <=4.0.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-discard-overridden
postcss-merge-longhand  <=4.0.11
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
Depends on vulnerable versions of stylehacks
node_modules/postcss-merge-longhand
postcss-merge-rules  <=4.0.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-merge-rules
postcss-minify-font-values  <=4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-minify-font-values
postcss-minify-gradients  <=4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-minify-gradients
postcss-minify-params  <=4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-minify-params
postcss-minify-selectors  <=4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors
postcss-modules-extract-imports  <=1.2.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-extract-imports
postcss-modules-local-by-default  <=1.2.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-local-by-default
postcss-modules-scope  <=1.1.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-scope
postcss-modules-values  <=1.3.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-modules-values
postcss-normalize-charset  <=4.0.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-charset
postcss-normalize-display-values  <=4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-display-values
postcss-normalize-positions  <=4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-positions
postcss-normalize-repeat-style  <=4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-repeat-style
postcss-normalize-string  <=4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-string
postcss-normalize-timing-functions  <=4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-timing-functions
postcss-normalize-unicode  <=4.0.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-unicode
postcss-normalize-url  1.1.0 - 4.0.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-url
postcss-normalize-whitespace  <=4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-normalize-whitespace
postcss-ordered-values  <=4.1.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-ordered-values
postcss-reduce-initial  <=4.0.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-reduce-initial
postcss-reduce-transforms  <=4.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-reduce-transforms
postcss-unique-selectors  <=4.0.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/postcss-unique-selectors
purgecss  <=1.0.1 || 2.0.1-beta.0 - 3.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/purgecss
stylehacks  <=4.0.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
node_modules/stylehacks

request  *
Severity: moderate
Server-Side Request Forgery in Request - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-p8p7-x288-28g6
Depends on vulnerable versions of tough-cookie
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/request
request-promise-core  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of request
node_modules/request-promise-core
request-promise-native  >=1.0.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of request
Depends on vulnerable versions of request-promise-core
Depends on vulnerable versions of tough-cookie
node_modules/request-promise-native

terser  <4.8.1
Severity: high
Terser insecure use of regular expressions leads to ReDoS - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4wf5-vphf-c2xc
No fix available
node_modules/terser

tough-cookie  <4.1.3
Severity: moderate
tough-cookie Prototype Pollution vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-72xf-g2v4-qvf3
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/tough-cookie

56 vulnerabilities (44 moderate, 12 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

can anyone help me?thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried running `npm audit fix` and then updating `post-css` to version 8.4.31 or higher as suggested in the error message? What happened?